# Python: how to share class attribute between derived classes?

Tags: python, class-attributes

I want to share some information between all the instances of some class and all it's derived classes.

```
class Base():
    cv = "some value"  # information I want to share

    def print_cv(self, note):
        print("{}: {}".format(note, self.cv))

    @classmethod
    def modify_cv(cls, new_value):
        # do some class-specific stuff
        cls.cv = new_value

class Derived(Base):
    pass

b = Base()
d = Derived()

b.print_cv("base")
d.print_cv("derived")
```

Output is as expected (instances of both classes see correct class attribute):

```
base: some value
derived: some value
```

I can change the value of this class attribute and everything is still fine:

```
# Base.cv = "new value"
b.modify_cv("new value")
b.print_cv("base")       # -> base: new value
d.print_cv("derived")    # -> derived: new value
```

So far so good. The problem is that the "connection" between Base and Derived classes can be broken if I access `cv` via derived class:

```
# Derived.cv = "derived-specific value"
d.modify_cv("derived-specific value")
b.print_cv("base")       # -> base: new value
d.print_cv("derived")    # -> derived: derived-specific value
```

This behavior is expected, but this is not what I want!

I understand why `a` and `b` see different values of `cv` - because they are instances of different classes. I have overridden `cv` value in derived class and now derived class behaves differently, I've used this feature many times.

But for my current task I need `a` and `b` always use the same `cv`!

**UPDATE**

I have updated the question and now it better describes the real-life situation. Actually I did not modify `cv` value like this:

```
Base.cv = "new value"
```

modifications were done in some classmethods (actually all these class methods were implemented in `Base` class).

And now solution became obvious, I just need to modify the method slightly:

```
class Base():
    @classmethod
    def modify_cv(cls, new_value):
        #cls.cv = new_value
        Base.cv = new_value
```

Thank you all for discussion and ideas (in the begining I was going to use getters/setters and module-level attribute)

Comment: So just assign the value to `Base.cv` instead of `Derived.cv`? Seems to be the easiest solution, no?

Comment: @Aran-Fey My situation is a little more complicated, `cv` is accessed and modified by classmethods of several derived classes. I guess I can always specify Base classname in the involved methods, but may be there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

`classmethod` is useful when you need to know which class is calling the method, but if you want the same behaviour regardless of the class that's calling the method, you could use `staticmethod` instead. You can then access the class variable simply through the base class's name with `Base.cv`:

```
class Base:
    cv = "some value"  # information I want to share

    def print_cv(self, note):
        print("{}: {}".format(note, self.cv))

    @staticmethod
    def modify_cv(new_value):
        Base.cv = new_value
```

You can still call it on any instance or subclass, but it always changes `Base.cv`:

```
>>> b = Base()
>>> d = Derived()
>>> Base.cv == Derived.cv == b.cv == d.cv == "some value"
True
>>> d.modify_cv("new value")
>>> Base.cv == Derived.cv == b.cv == d.cv == "new value"
True
```

---

**Update:**

If you still need access to the class for other reasons, use `classmethod` with the `cls` argument as you did before, but still access the base class's variable through `Base.cv` rather than `cls.cv`:

```
@classmethod
def modify_cv(cls, new_value):
    do_stuff_with(cls)
    Base.cv = new_value
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that in this particular example `staticmethod` will do. In my case methods which modified `cv` have to be classmethods, there is no explicit setter for `cv`.

Comment: @jsbueno Please check, `staticmethod` works fine in this example.

Comment: ok - it works - and it is not incorrect, as it is the simplest way for people not knowing certain mechanisms of the language  - it is just that there is a more proper mechanism.

Comment: @lesnik I've updated the answer, you can just use `classmethod` and access `Base.cv` directly. **Edit:** But this you already knew since it's in your main post. Right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `__setattr__` on the class of the class, i.e. a metaclass:

```
class InheritedClassAttributesMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        cls = None

        if not hasattr(self, key):
            # The attribute doesn't exist anywhere yet,
            # so just set it here
            cls = self
        else:
            # Find the base class that's actually storing it
            for cls in self.__mro__:
                if key in cls.__dict__:
                    break
        type.__setattr__(cls, key, value)


class Base(metaclass=InheritedClassAttributesMeta):
    cv = "some value"


class Derived(Base):
    pass


print(Derived.cv)
Derived.cv = "other value"
print(Base.cv)
```

Using metaclasses is often overkill, so directly specifying `Base` might be better.

To avoid unwanted side effects with this solution, consider checking first if `key` is in some predefined set of attribute names before changing the behaviour.

Comment: I'd rather use a property on the metaclass than messing with `__setattr__`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how? That would create a property for every class.

Comment: You do *not* need a metaclass here, it's absolute overkill! See my answer

Comment: This is overkill - on the other hand, the metaclass solution will work for any attribute without requiring an explicit setter for each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, inside a method, you can use the bare  `__class__` variable name to mean the actual class the method is defined in.

This differs from the  `cls` arg that is passed to classmethods, or `self.__class__` on regular methods, that will refer to a subclass if the method is invoked in a subclass. Thus, `cls.attr = value` would set the value on the subclass class' `__dict__`, and the attribute value will be independent on that subclass from that point on. This is what you are getting there.

Instead, you can use:

```
class MyClass:
   cv  = "value"

   @classmethod # this is actually optional
   def modify_cv(cls, new_value):
        __class__.cv = new_value
```

`__class__` is created automatically in Python 3 by
the mechanism that allows one to write 
parameterless form of `super`